# GoogleFinance: Return Data Without Column Header

Tags: google-sheets

In a Stocks spreadsheet, I now need to get the AUDUSD currency rate for a particular date, so that I can assess the exchange rate gain/loss as well as stock gain/loss.

To get the specific date, I used:

`=QUERY( GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDUSD", "price", DATE(2021,7,1), DATE(2021,7,2), "DAILY"),  "SELECT Col2" )`

However, this returns the column **header** "Close" as well as the value, so I tried using OFFSET in the QUERY statement:

`=QUERY( GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDUSD", "price", DATE(2021,7,1), DATE(2021,7,2), "DAILY"),  "SELECT Col2 OFFSET 1" )`

Oddly, this returned just the header, without the value.  I haven't been able to find the Google documentation for QUERY(), so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions, or pointers to the docs, would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `label` in Query we can rename the header of data, here we rename with `blank` hence it returns only the value of price from col2

`=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDUSD", "price", DATE(2021,7,1), DATE(2021,7,2), "DAILY"),"select Col2 label Col2''")`

[QUERY](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)